# YT search API to search for Arabic speaking channels locally in Israel

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

How can I retrieve all Arabic speaking channels locally in Israel.

Using the API explorer, I don't see such an option.

1. Which fields are mandatory for search to call the search API?
2. Is there any way to fulfill this task?

Update:

[API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%22%5D%2C%22maxResults%22%3A50%2C%22regionCode%22%3A%22IL%22%2C%22relevanceLanguage%22%3A%22ar%22%2C%22type%22%3A%5B%22video%22%5D%7D)

I couldn't get results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of parameters in the [API v3 Docs for Search](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) that you can play around with, some in particular you might find helpful are:

- location
- locationRadius
- regionCode
- relevanceLanguage

and you'll need to set `type = "channel"` to return only channels.

The only *mandatory* parameter is part which is what data you want returned from your results. For this search call, you only have one option for part, which is "snippet".

This is the only way to do it simply within your multiple parameters, and it will take 100 quota per search, assuming you have an API key already.

If you press 'Try This API' on the right, it'll even give you code snippets you can copy in a variety of languages, since you didn't specify one in the prompt.

Depending on the language, a call could look like the following:

```
GET https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&location=Israel&regionCode=IL&relevanceLanguage=ar&type=channel&key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1
```

Comment: `Search.list` has a quota cost of 100 units per call.

Comment: As for mandatory, if I enter "part" and nothing else - I get an argument error. So other params are mandatory as well?

Comment: [API Explorer][1]

I couldn't get results

  [1]: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%22%5D%2C%22maxResults%22%3A50%2C%22regionCode%22%3A%22IL%22%2C%22relevanceLanguage%22%3A%22ar%22%2C%22type%22%3A%5B%22video%22%5D%7D

Comment: Did you use 'part=snippet'? Is your API key valid? Part is the only required parameter, as per the documentation I linked.